# How to know which iteration of the array.map I'm on?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm new to react-native.
I want to use `array.map()`  to render out some jsx in the UI.
I'm looping over the  API response which is as follows:

```
chosenProducts = [
{id:1 , name:"carpet"} ,
{id:24 , name:"toy"} ,
{id:28 , name:"laser"} ,
{id:137 , name:"map"} ,
]
```

I use `chosenProducts.map((prod)=>{some jsx})` to map over the array.
but I want to add a key-value pair `ex: order:1` to each product to be able to order them in the UI.

How can I dynamically add the order to them without changing the API response?

note: I'm using TypeScript

ps: I will use the order attribute to dynamically style the products. so it's not just the ordering!

Comment: The array map callback has a second parameter that indicates the current iteration index: `chosenProducts.map((prod, index)=>{some jsx})` More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter in the map function destructuring is the index of the item in the array

```
chosenProducts.map((prod, id)=>{some jsx }) // add id here
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map